# Powershell Copy-Item to remote session fails randomly

Tags: powershell, remote-server

I'm using this Powershell command to copy a folder, which contains many sub-folders and files from my local machine to a remote VM.

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $desComputerName -Credential $credentials
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $destinationFolder -Recurse -Force -ToSession $session
```

Most of the times it works just fine, everything is copied, but sometimes it doesn't.
This is the error I always get when it fails:

```
Copy-Item : Failed to create directory <A-Random-Folder> on remote destination.
```

Here's the full error log:

```
Copy-Item : Starting a command on the remote server failed with the following error message : <s:Envelope 
xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer" 
xmlns:e="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/eventing" xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/enumeration" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd" xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd">
<s:Header><a:Action>http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman/fault</a:Action><a:MessageID>uuid:BE54F3C6-3E48-40CC-882
6-29DECA14BAC7</a:MessageID><p:OperationID s:mustUnderstand="false">uuid:03909886-0D49-489B-AD87-AC5654A64257</p:Operat
ionID><p:SequenceId>1</p:SequenceId><a:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:To><a:Rela
tesTo>uuid:82E5942D-D7CC-40B9-B16D-2E2A07635273</a:RelatesTo></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><s:Code><s:Value>s:Receiver</s
:Value><s:Subcode><s:Value>w:InternalError</s:Value></s:Subcode></s:Code><s:Reason><s:Text 
xml:lang="en-US"></s:Text></s:Reason><s:Detail><unknown></s:Detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope> For more 
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At MyFolder\Deploy.ps1:63 char:5
+     Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $destinationFolder -Re ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Management.Automation.PowerShell:PowerShell) [Copy-Item], PSRe 
   motingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileRemoteExecutionError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Failed to create directory 'MyDestinationFolder\CKEditor\plugins\pastefromword\filter' on 
remote destination.
At MySourceFolder\Deploy.ps1:63 char:5
+     Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $destinationFolder -Re ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (MyDestinationFolder\CKEditor\plugins\pastefromword\filter:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToCreateDirectory,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

To Sum up:

- I'm using the remote computer's administrator credential to initialize the session
- The Copy-Item operation does not always fail
- The folder where the operation fails to create is not always the same

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but: Did you try [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for that task?

Comment: +1 for robocopy solution. Search the Stack overflow forum to find some very cool powershell robocopy scripts. TO me, i would assume its some sort of networking issue (latency/dropped packets/etc) that is causign ths issue. There isn't a whole lot of ways to troubleshoot a "random" issue without actually looking at the picture as a whole.

Comment: The problem with RoboCopy may be that there is not file share access to the target (SMB/CIFS).
Xcopy actually works quite well for most such copies when the file share is available.  (Robocopy is better but usually not worth the extra effort.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas that might or might not help:

Check the total length of the destination folders & files -- since you are copying "many folders and files" you may be reaching one of the limits:

> 240 characters for directory paths
>
> 260 characters for file fullnames

Another idea is to use the -container switch on the copy which is documented as: "Indicates that this cmdlet preserves container objects during the copy operation."

As others have suggesting, if you can use a file share, consider Xcopy or Robocopy.

I have excellent results copying gigabytes of deep directories during automated  builds using XCopy.

Robocopy is more capable and can control retries much better, but is usually not worth the extra trouble of its very extensive and complicated switches.

Comment: The issue for sure does not relate path limitation :)
Anyway, I switched to robocopy and it works like charm. Thanks for your suggestion.